# Every closed subspace of a compact space is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,\tau_{X})$ be a compact topological space and let $A \subset X$, $\tau_{X}$ - closed. We need show that $(A, \tau_{A})$ is a compact topological subspace.

Proof:

Let $U = \{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in L} $ be a open cover of $X$. Then, there exists $\{U_1, \ldots, U_k\} \subset  U$ such that:

X = $U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_k \implies  A = X \cap A = ( U_1 \cup ... \cup U_k) \cap A = \cup V_\lambda ; V_\lambda = U_\lambda \cap A \in \tau_{A}.$ Therefore, (A, $\tau_{A}$) is a compact  subspace.

In particular, $U\cap A$ is a $\tau_{A}$ - open conver of $A.$

Is it correct?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you want to show that $A$ is compact, then you need to start with an open cover of $A$ and then reduce that to a finite subcover. Notice that none of your proof uses the fact that $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Hint: $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ open cover of $A$ . 
Then
$\{U_{\alpha},X\setminus A\}$ cover $X$

Comment: To elaborate on Ethan's comment, to prove compactness of any set, you need to first chose an arbitrary open cover of that particular set and not any other set and show that it has a finite subcover. What you have done is taken a cover of $X$ and not $A$. Notice that it proves nothing. If $A=(0,1)$ and I pick an open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ of $[0,1]$(the compact interval) then obviously $A=[0,1]\cap(0,1) = \cup_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap A)$ . Does this mean $(0,1)$ is compact ?. Of course not by Heine Borel Theorem. So start with an open cover of $A$ and use the hint of Lost in Space.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to show is that for any open cover $\bigcup_{i \in J} V_j $ of $A$ you can find a finite subcover $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$. So to answer your question no it is not entirely right. Because
what you proved is that if you have a finite subcover for $X$ you have one for $A$, which is only a part of the whole proof which should go as:

Since $A$ is closed $X\backslash A$ is open, and thus $\{ X \backslash A , \bigcup_{i \in J} V_{i}\}$ is an open cover of $X$. Compactness of $X$ allows you to find a finite subcover $\{ X \backslash A , \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{i}\}$ $\textbf{denoted that the index goes now up to $n$ thus finite}$. Because $A \subset X$  we have that $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{i}$ and thats what we wanted. $\{V_{i}\}^n_{i=1}$ is a finite subcover of A and $V_i$ was arbitrary thus $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's incorrect. You need to start from an open cover of $A$, not of $X$.

Suppose $\mathcal{V}$ is an open cover of $A$, so the sets $V\in\mathcal{V}$ are open in $X$ and
$$
A\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{V}
$$
Now consider $\mathcal{V}'=\mathcal{V}\cup(X\setminus A)$, which is obviously an open cover of $X$ and conclude: you can find $V_1,\dots,V_n\in\mathcal{V}'$ such that
$$
X=V_1\cup V_2\cup\dots\cup V_n
$$
If $X\setminus A$ is not among the $V_i$, you're done. Otherwise, without loss of generality $X\setminus A=V_n$ and
$$
A\subseteq V_1\cup\dots\cup V_{n-1}
$$